# code doesn't work for stopwords from each row of column CONTENT

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

This line doesn't remove stopwords from each row of column CONTENT

```py
 df = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\mukesh_gupta\PycharmProjects\Doc_analysis\src\student99.csv')

df.columns = ["FILE", "EXT", "CONTENT", "CATEGORY"]
df['CONTENT'] = df['CONTENT'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if word not in (stop)]))
```

Comment: could you provide a wrong example row? and what would be the desired outcome?

Comment: .........exist edw(interact end user / poc need this)......................................................     (I believ that) mar planet.................................... i want to remove (this that) like stopwords from sentence in dataframe column named CONTENT

Comment: sorry what is your example?